# How should I deploy the trained model from google colab to my computer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colaboratory for training my model through a dataset that I have uploaded to `colab.research.google.com`. After completing my training process I want to use the trained parameters in my local PC and create the same model with trained values locally. What procedure should I follow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to connect your notebook to your google drive by:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

then after training, save your trained model as:

```
model.save("/content/gdrive/My Drive/name_of_your_model.h5")
```

Open your google drive, download the saved file name_of_your_model.h5. Then on your local pc load the model

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model(<path to your model file on local machine>)
```

Now you have the trained model on your local pc

Comment: After entering the authentication code from the given url for accessing drive the code execution is not getting completed. What could be the reason? Provided i have good network connectivity.

Comment: that's strange... never happened to me

Comment: maybe the code is corrupted somehow? check what happens when you enter obviously wrong code

Comment: can't check because the final output conforming whether drive is mounted or not, is not being generated. I had already tried it.